# Ranking data based on first onset

Tags: r, algorithm, rank

```
subset <- 
  structure(list(MEMORY1 = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), MEMORY2 = c(3L, 2L, 
  3L, 1L), MEMORY3 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), MEMORY4 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L), MEMORY5 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), MEMORY6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    MEMORY7 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), MEMORY8 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("MEMORY1", 
  "MEMORY2", "MEMORY3", "MEMORY4", "MEMORY5", "MEMORY6", "MEMORY7", 
  "MEMORY8"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

subset
#   MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8
# 1       3       3       2       2       2       1       2       1
# 2       2       2       2       2       2       1       2       1
# 3       3       3       3       2       2       1       2       1
# 4       2       1       2       2       2       1       2       1
```

I have a data set of 8 memory items at 4 points in time (4 rows). I am trying to rank the memory items in terms of first onset, which is defined as the first time the memory item has a value > 1.

For the above `subset`, items 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 7 would have rank 1 because at time `1`, these items had a value of > 1. As for items 6 and 8, their values = 1 across all 4 time points, so I would assign a rank of `NA` to them.

```
ranks = rep(0, items)
ranks = sapply(subset, function(x) which(x > 1)[1L])
ranks
# MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8 
#       1       1       1       1       1      NA       1      NA
```

However, since `MEMORY1` and `MEMORY2` have a value of 3 at time `1` and `MEMORY3`, `MEMORY4`, `MEMORY5` and `MEMORY7` have a value of 2 at time `1`, I want to rank `MEMORY1` and `MEMORY2` before the other four items. So I want an output that looks like

```
ranks
# MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8 
#       1       1       2       2       2      NA       2      NA
```

So 1) rank by first onset 2) rank items with highest value as 1, the next highest value as 2, etc.

How can I accomplish step 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you the values:

```
wheremax <- sapply(subset,function(x) { which(x > 1)[1L] }) #your code
as.matrix(subset)[cbind(wheremax,1:ncol(subset))]
[1]  3  3  2  2  2 NA  2 NA
```

You can then get a rank:

```
DTrank <- rank(-as.matrix(subset)[cbind(wheremax,1:ncol(subset))] + wheremax * max(subset), ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep")
[1]  1  1  3  3  3 NA  3 NA
```

This adds a penalty to each additional row, equal to the max value anywhere in the data.frame. It ensures that a value in row two will always be ranked below a value in row one

But it is not ordered as increments (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ...). Higher numbers will always have lower values though. Open to suggestions if there is a better way.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but for a subset such as `structure(list(MEMORY1 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), MEMORY2 = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), MEMORY3 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), MEMORY4 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), MEMORY5 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 4L), MEMORY6 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
    MEMORY7 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), MEMORY8 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("MEMORY1", 
"MEMORY2", "MEMORY3", "MEMORY4", "MEMORY5", "MEMORY6", "MEMORY7", 
"MEMORY8"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")` Item 6 should be ranked last because its first onset is later than the others. However that is not reflected in your suggestion.

Comment: @Adrian sorry my mistake, I missed that nuance. Edited to reflect

Answer (score 0):

First, get the rank *and* the value:

```
  df <- sapply(subset, function(x) {
  tmp <- which(x > 1)[1L]; 
  c(rank=tmp, val=ifelse(length(tmp>0), x[tmp], NA))
})

# adding "memory" field to keep track of the memories
df <- data.frame(t(df), memory=1:nrow(df))

# let's add a little excitement otherwise hard to tell if it's working
df[3,1] <- 2
# dealing with NA by giving them infinite rank
df[is.na(df)] <- Inf
# val will be sorted by increasing values, so take the neg because we want them decreasing 
df$val <- -df$val
final_rank_order <- order(df$rank, df$val, decreasing = F)
df <- df[final_rank_order,]

df$final <- 1
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if(df$rank[i]==df$rank[i-1] & df$val[i]==df$val[i-1])
    df$final[i] <- df$final[i-1]
  else 
    df$final[i] <- df$final[i-1]+1
}
```

At this point we have this:

```
> df
        rank  val memory final
MEMORY1    1   -3      1     1
MEMORY2    1   -3      2     1
MEMORY4    1   -2      4     2
MEMORY5    1   -2      5     2
MEMORY7    1   -2      7     2
MEMORY3    2   -2      3     3
MEMORY6  Inf -Inf      6     4
MEMORY8  Inf -Inf      8     4
```

Final touch:

```
final_ranks <- df$final[order(df$memory)]

> final_ranks
[1] 1 1 3 2 2 4 2 4
```

I cannot believe it had to be so hacky. It really thought it was trivial at first. There must be a better way!

Note that I changed your data a bit beause you only had 1s and NA so it was not possible to tell if the code was working.

Comment: I like the idea of organizing the information in `rank_and_val` first, but I want to assign the same ranking to items with the same rank and value in `rank_and_val`, so essentially I would like to assign a rank of 1 to both `MEMORY1` AND `MEMORY2`. How might I do that?

Comment: @Adrian Edited my answer, now it does what you want